# Varying the Entries of a PSD Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Okay, I am going to do my best articulating my question. Suppose that $P = [p_{ij}] \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb{C})$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. Then its off-diagonal entries satisfy $|p_{ij}| \le \sqrt{ p_{ii} p_{jj}}$, which says that the the entry $p_{ij}$ lies in the closed disc of radius $\sqrt{p_{ii} p_{jj}}$ centered at the origin in the complex plane. My question is, very roughly,

> If we replace the off-diagonal entry $p_{ij}$ with $z \in \overline{D}(0, \sqrt{p_{ii}p_{jj}})$, will $P$ still be PSD?

Now, I know this is true in the 2x2 case, but I doubt it will be true in higher dimensional situations. It seems that we need another condition to be satisfied. In the 3x3 case, the above condition only guarantees that the 2x2 principle minors of $P$ are PSD, but then we have to worry about the overall determinant of $P$. So, I suppose my *true* question is,

> What additional condition(s) must be added in order for us to conclude that $P$ remains PSD?

Comment: Can you refer me to where it is proven that for PSD matrix $P$ we have $|p_{ij}|\leq \sqrt{p_{ii}p_{jj}}$ where $i\neq j$?

Comment: @etotheipi Hi. Sorry for the delay. The only way I can think of proving the statement is, first, by noting that $P$ is PSD iff $P$ is Gram. I.e., there exist vectors $v_1,...,v_n \in \Bbb{C}^k$ for some $k \in \Bbb{N}$ s.t. $P = [\langle v_i,v_j \rangle]$. Hence $|p_{ij}| = |\langle v_i,v_j \rangle| \le ||v_i|| \cdot ||v_j|| = \sqrt{p_{ii} p_{jj}}$.